# Portfolio Optimization about text breakline

Tags: algorithm, line-breaks, portfolio, np-complete

Given an array of words and line number n.
How can I get the least width, less than n lines.
For example,
**words:** ["AA", "AA", "A", "AAAAAA", "AA"]
**lines:** 2
we can get
[
   "AA AA A",
   "AAAAAA AA",                //this line is widthest，so we regard this as width
]
So the answer is 8.
If we change lines to 3, so that we can get
[
   "AA AA A",
   "AAAAAA",                   //this line is widthest，so we regard this as width
   “AA”
]
So the answer is 6.
**Notice**：
**words:** ["AA", "A", "AA", "A", "AA"]
**lines:** 5
we can only get 3 lines result，and the answer is 3
[
   "AA A",
"AA A",
"AA"
]
Because if we Reduce the width,the result will become
[
   "AA",
   "A",
   "AA", 
"A" ,
"AA"
]
**I want to know if this problem is NP-Complete and if there is any similar problem.**

Comment: Last example is a bit confusing.
What would be the answer in the last case? 
2?

Comment: First example, the answer is 9, not 8, isn't it? And width of "AA A" is 4, not 3, or will the blanks be removed? Else, data like "AA", "bb", "C", "ddddd", "EE" would be better with results like "AAbbC", "dddddEE".

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your finding. Have a look at the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem Which is a bit similar to your Problem

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Ignore the blanks in this problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this problem is NP-Complete. Your problem is a variation of the [Bin Packing Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem)

A greedy algorithm for your case could look like this: Sort your words by length (descending) and process them in this order. Put each string in the line that has the smallest width yet (if there are several with the same width just choose one).

Comment: I have thought about the Bin Packing Problem,but in that problem, you can sort and use greedy algorithm.But for mine, we can't use this way.Do you have advanced idea.

Comment: @US sketched an idea for a simple greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure about NP-Completeness.

Assuming, that we need one space to separate words. That's in accordance with what you show in the examples, but not how you count: "AA A" has width 4 in my opinion.

We have a list of words of lengths (2, 2, 1, 6, 2) and want to split it over n lines.

So the total length is the sum of lengths (13) + the number of elements - 1, because one seperator for each pair, - number of lines, which build a natural seperator, + 1 => list.lenghts.sum + list.count - lines.

So for 2 lines, this is 18 - 2 = 16, for 3 lines 18 - 3 = 15.

We divide that length by lines, to get the optimum length for each line, which is, for 2 lines 16/2 = 8, for 3 lines 15/3 = 3. In case of a rest from division, we have to round up.

Now we fill a recursive function with our input. For the current line, we collect as long as the line is below the optimum. If adding one more word would exceed the optimum, we compare, whether adding the word will exceed the line more, than omitting the word would waste space. We go for the smaller difference and repeat the procedure for the rest.

But I haven't tested this for evil crafted input.

```
class Linesplitter (text: String) {
    val words = text.split (" ")
    val count = words.length
    val sizes = words.map(_.length)
    val total = sizes.sum + count // including delimiters and + 1

    def delta (a: Int, b:Int) = if (a < b) b-a else (a-b)

    def split (lines: Int): List[List[String]] = {
    //
        def betterToAdd (currentLen: Int, lenToAdd: Int, opt: Int) : Boolean = {
            val dsmall = delta (currentLen, opt)
            val dlong  = delta (opt, currentLen + 1 + lenToAdd)
            dsmall > dlong
        }

        def optimalSplit (lv: List[String], currentLine: List[String], currentLen: Int, opt: Int): List[List[String]] = lv match {
            case Nil => List (currentLine.reverse)
            case x :: xs => if (betterToAdd (currentLen, x.length, opt)) {
                    optimalSplit (xs, x :: currentLine, currentLen + 1 + x.length, opt)
                } else {
                    currentLine.reverse :: optimalSplit (xs, List (x), x.length, opt)
                }
        }
        /* just printing, not generating any return
        def printOptimalSplit (lv: List[String], currentLine: List[String], currentLen: Int, opt: Int): Unit = lv match {
            case Nil => println (currentLine.reverse.mkString (" "))
            case x :: xs => if (betterToAdd (currentLen, x.length, opt)) {
                    printOptimalSplit (xs, x :: currentLine, currentLen + 1 + x.length, opt)
                } else {
                    println (currentLine.reverse.mkString (" "))
                    printOptimalSplit (xs, List (x), x.length, opt)
                }
        }
        */

        val optimum = (total - 1) / lines
        // println (f"n: $lines%2s   Optimum: $optimum")
        optimalSplit (words.toList, List(), 0, optimum)
    }
}

val ls = new Linesplitter ("""Seit je hat Aufklärung im umfassendsten Sinn fortschreitenden Denkens das Ziel verfolgt, von den Menschen die Furcht zu nehmen und sie als Herren einzusetzen. Aber die vollends aufgeklärte Erde strahlt im Zeichen triumphalen Unheils. Das Programm der Aufklärung war die Entzauberung der Welt. Sie wollte die Mythen auflösen und Einbildung durch Wissen stürzen. Bacon, »der Vater der experimentellen Philosophie«[1], hat die Motive schon versammelt. Er verachtet die Adepten der Tradition, die »zuerst glauben, daß andere wissen, was sie nicht wissen; und nachher, daß sie selbst wissen, was sie nicht wissen. Leichtgläubigkeit jedoch, Widerwille gegen den Zweifel, Unbesonnenheit im Antworten, Prahlerei mit Bildung, Scheu zu widersprechen, Interessiertheit, Lässigkeit in eigener Forschung, Wortfetischismus, Stehenbleiben bei bloßen Teilerkenntnissen: dies und Ähnliches hat die glückliche Ehe des menschlichen Verstandes mit der Natur der Dinge verhindert, und ihn statt dessen an eitle Begriffe und planlose Experimente verkuppelt: die Frucht und Nachkommenschaft einer so rühmlichen Verbindung kann man sich leicht vorstellen. Die Druckerpresse, eine grobe Erfindung; die Kanone, eine die schon nahe lag; der Kompaß, in gewissem Grad bereits früher bekannt: welche Veränderung haben nicht diese drei hervorgebracht - die eine im Zustand der Wissenschaft, die andere in dem des Krieges, die dritte in dem der Finanzen, des Handels und der Schiffahrt! Und auf diese, sage ich, ist man nur zufällig gestolpert und gestoßen. Also die Überlegenheit des Menschen liegt im Wissen, das duldet keinen Zweifel. Darin sind viele Dinge aufbewahrt, welche Könige mit all ihren Schätzen nicht kaufen können, über die ihr Befehl nicht gebietet, von denen ihre Kundschafter und Zuträger keine Nachricht bringen, zu deren Ursprungsländern ihre Seefahrer und Entdecker nicht segeln können. Heute beherrschen wir die Natur in unserer bloßen Meinung und sind ihrem Zwange unterworfen; ließen wir uns jedoch von ihr in der Erfindung leiten, so würden wir ihr in der Praxis gebieten.«""")
(20 to 100 by 20).map (i => List ("\n") :: ls.split (i)).foreach {_.foreach (l => println (l.mkString (" ")))}
```

Sample output, generated for lines = 60:

```
Seit je hat Aufklärung im umfassendsten
Sinn fortschreitenden Denkens das
Ziel verfolgt, von den Menschen die
Furcht zu nehmen und sie als Herren
einzusetzen. Aber die vollends
aufgeklärte Erde strahlt im Zeichen
triumphalen Unheils. Das Programm
der Aufklärung war die Entzauberung
der Welt. Sie wollte die Mythen
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array is split into contiguous sections, this problem is not NP-Complete. In that case, we can solve it with binary search on the target width. `O(w log n)` time, where `n` is the total number of characters and `w` the total number of words in the array.